# I deleted my bitoin wallet many years ago near the start

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, wallet-recovery, recover-private-key, slush

I know which pool I was a member of and maybe i should ask them instead?

I'm trying to find out how or if i can recover them

I had 3 Bitcoins way back at the begining back when gpu mining was a thing. I have tried to recovering the files but no luck. Atleast non that still have the names intacted. Or file structure intact. So if theres something i can run that could look for just certain bits of info that might find or hold the private key

i think I found the public key they were sent to but idk if that helps or if its even the right one. Since I found it when I logged onto my pool miner website but its been so long that everything has changed if even remember the miner i used though if that helps.

Wish I hadn't deleteled the files off my computer they were worth like 20 dollars back than. Maybe less. And again I dont know much about how bitcoin wallets even work or how to even go about re

Answer (score 0):

They are gone forever. You will go insane hunting for those lost coins, like I almost did. Even as late as 2014 I would send the same amount (3 BTC) to my account on a marketplace which then shut down and took my coins with it. I was naive. And I lost MANY more coins through further carelessness. I regret it every day. I could have lived like a king instead of like a hobo today. But there's nothing that can be done short of inventing a working time machine.